# How to avoid synchronous AJAX without spawning sessions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multithreading, session

My page loads all necessary data from the server at startup via AJAX. This includes user's language settings, various classifiers, some business data etc.

The problem I am facing is that when the user first comes to the page, all these different AJAX calls are kicked off at the same time. This means that on the server side, most of them are assigned different JSESSIONID-s (I am using Spring on Tomcat 8 without any complex configuration). As a result, some of the data is initialized on the server side in one session, but the browser might end up using a different session in the end and does not have access to the data set up by earlier ajax calls.

I wanted to solve this by using a fast synchronous AJAX call in the very beginning so that after it returns and gets a JSESSIONID, all subsequent calls would be made in this original session.

```
$.ajax("api/language", {
    type: "GET", 
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) { 
        //do stuff;
    }
});
// more AJAX calls
```

It works, but I get warning messages that synchronized XMLHttpRequest on main thread is deprecated. Now - I understand the reasons why such a synchronized call is bad for UI in general, but what other options are there available for me if I want to force all AJAX calls to use the same server side session?

I can achieve the same result by using a callback and just placing all the rest of my page initialization code in there, executing it in the 'success' section of the first AJAX call, but that wouldn't that have exactly the same effect as synchronizing on main?

Comment: Why are you setting a content type header on a GET request?

Comment: Because I did not know any better. I will remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd initiate the session when loading the HTML document rather than when requesting something from the API.

Alternatively, trigger the subsequent API calls from the success callback of the first one.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to initiate the session when loading the HTML document? It is just a static HTML page and I expected it to spawn a session but it does not. Perhaps there is some misconfiguration on the server side...

Comment: I don't know JSP, but presumably there is some function call you make in it to start a session. Make the HTML document a JSP and put that function call in it.

Comment: Yes, I could achieve the result with JSP, but I was hoping I could keep the page itself as HTML so that I would have the option of directly packaging it into a HTML5 App. Now that I think about it, creating the session while loading the page itself really never was an option.

I will probably just use the success callback

Answer (score 2):

#### "Hacky" solution

You really give your own solution at the end: wrap everything in an asynchronous AJAX call. It is similiar to the synchronous solution, but this way you can set up a loading animation, or something similar.

---

#### "Nice" solution

Another, possible nicer solution. When the user arrives, you can redirect to the starting page of your web application with the generated jsessionid. This can be done with a servlet. I am quite sure that Tomcat can be configured to do this without writing your own code.